# Pandoc LaTeX to DOCX conversion \cite[arg1]{arg2} using CSL misses arg1

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This works, yeah! \cite{Knu86} and \cite[Page 121]{Knu86}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}

pandoc -F pandoc-crossref --bibliography=MWE.bib MWE.tex -o MWE.docx
```

Output:

```
This works, yeah! (Knuth 1986) and (Knuth 1986 Page 121)
Knuth, Donald E. 1986. *The Texbook*.
```

whereas,

```
pandoc -F pandoc-crossref --bibliography=MWE.bib --csl computing-surveys.csl MWE.tex -o MWE.docx
```

Output:

```
This works, yeah! [1] and [1]
[1] Donald E. Knuth. 1986. *The texbook*.
```

Comment: Have you checked if `computing-surveys.csl` supports page numbers?

Comment: I am not sure on how do I check any csl supporting page numbers. Most of them fail.

Comment: So. Turns out, that `pandoc` doesn't parse 'Page' in the first argument. You have to write either `\cite[121]{Knu86}` or `\cite[p. 121]{Knu86}`(and respectively `\cite[120--123]{Knu86}` or `\cite[pp. 120--123]{Knu86}`).

Comment: Thanks @DG'. The Chicago_name_year default csl also does not adds the comma after the reference item in the first instance. Surprised, the instances that you have mentioned does yield results with ":" as a separator with computing-surveys.csl. Let me check the syntax of the other CSLs.